# Setting the number of Maximum iterations in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to know how I can set the number of Maximum Iterations(want to increase it) in MATLAB.
Does anybody knows?

I am using svmtrain

Comment: Usually you can set it for particular functions in the function call, what function are you using?

Answer (score 2):

you can pass options using either the 'SMO_OPTS' or the 'QUADPROG_OPTS' flags depending on which method you are using

```
SVMTRAIN(...,'QUADPROG_OPTS',OPTIONS)
```

or

```
SVMTRAIN(...,'SMO_OPTS',SMO_OPTIONS)
```

to create QP options, use optimset, to create SMO_OPTS, use svmsmoset.  either way, it's the maxiter field that you want to change.

---

doc svmsmoset

```
OPTIONS = SVMSMOSET('NAME1',VALUE1,'NAME2',VALUE2,...)
```

> MaxIter
>
> Maximum number of iterations of main loop. If this number is exceeded
>       before the algorithm converges then the algorithm stops and gives an
>       error. Default value is 15000.

By the way, help svmtrain or doc svmtrain contains all this info

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your options struct, using "statset"
eg

```
options = statset('maxIter',45000);
svmStruct = svmtrain(TrainingMat,Labels,'kernel_function', 'linear','options',options);
```